# php mysql LIKE with special characters does not work properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

So i am trying to do a LIKE query and get some results but the text that i pass has some special characters that break the query.

if we assume that the text is something like this:

```
var test `select` `query`="$newval + "dsadsa$ ? "$test ?
```

and i also have exactly the same text inside a column as VARCHAR

and then executing the query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%$text%'
```

says that there is no rows to return.

EDIT: when i post the data inside the database i simply use **mysql real escape string** and when i show the text where i click to search i put **htmlentities** on the text
then i **substr** it from 0 to 50 and do the search query

Comment: Could you please post the whole piece of code? The question is very obscure.

Comment: and in the select statement, should it be LIKE '%$test' ?

Comment: And if that's the case, are you looking strictly for '$test' to appear at the end of the string? As is, the above won't return anything. But you should see a result if you use LIKE '%$test%' insead...

Comment: @AlexanderMP, see edited post, @ldb, it was a typo, i also have % after the variable, @tomtheman, the string is just a dummy text i am trying to search **edit:** would it be able to cut all special characters and leave a-zA-Z0-9- only in the string with preg replace , will it work?

Comment: 1. what string is in $test? 2. what is the 'special character(s)' you are having trouble with? 3. do you have an example of content in 'column' that you are searching against?

Comment: `var test `select` `query`="$newval + "dsadsa$ ? "$test ?` is just a dumym text i insert into an textbox, submit it into the database, then try to search the column for datab and if i get any i want to return them.It seems that the special characters are causin the query to fail so it wont return anything back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysql_real_escape_string() which will escape any special characters in your string.

Answer (score -1):

Try to avoid writing variables directly into string, it may cause problems (+ it's really not nice):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%" . $text . "%'");
```

Of course make sure that the `$text` variable is really correct (`echo $text`), characters escaping may cause problems too and of course there can be many other things causing problems (this depends on architecture of your application - where you work with `$text`).